# Rでlmeを用いた解析をする際のエラー；invalid type (list) for variable 'data'

Tags: r

Rでlmeモデルを使った解析をしようとしていますが、以下のように解析しようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。原因を調べてみましたがわかりません。

データの形はdataframeであり、列の型はcharacterとintが混在しています。

**コード:**

```r
data <- read.table("data.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
model1 <- lme(y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,random=~1|data$Subject,data)
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```r
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~y + x1 + x2 +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'data'
```

Comment: `read.table("data.txt",header=T,sep="\t")<-data` ですが、これは `data <- read.table("data.txt",header=T,sep="\t")` ではありませんか？

Comment: そうしましたが、同じエラーです。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

下記にコードと出力を示しますが，`lme4` パッケージに含まれる [sleepstudy dataset](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/VCA/html/sleepstudy.html) を解析してもエラーは再現します。

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)

data <- sleepstudy
head(data)
model1 <- lme(Reaction ~ Days, random=~1|data$Subject, data)
```

```
   Reaction Days Subject
 1 249.5600    0     308
 2 258.7047    1     308
 3 250.8006    2     308
 4 321.4398    3     308
 5 356.8519    4     308
 6 414.6901    5     308
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~Reaction + Days + data + Subject,  :
   invalid type (list) for variable 'data'
```

エラーメッセージによると `formula` に `data` も含まれています。そこで，下記を試してみるとエラーは発生しなくなりました。

```
model1 <- lme(Reaction ~ Days, random=~1|Subject, data)
print(model1)
```

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
   Data: data
   Log-restricted-likelihood: -893.2325
   Fixed: Reaction ~ Days
 (Intercept)        Days
   251.40510    10.46729

 Random effects:
  Formula: ~1 | Subject
         (Intercept) Residual
 StdDev:    37.12383 30.99123

 Number of Observations: 180
 Number of Groups: 18
```